# How can I detect which process opened a URL on macOS

Tags: macos

As embarrasing as this is, I have a virus on my mac. Whoops.

The virus keeps opening up URLs in my default browser (which I can switch). I am hoping to trace which program opened the URLs.

Which leads me to the question in the title.

Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Use `pstree` (as explained [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/11770/linux-ps-f-tree-view-equivalent-on-osx)) to check the parent process of your browser session.

As a more general advice: backup your data en reinstall OSX. Removing a virus is hard and you are (almost) never sure if you removed it completely. If you really insist on removing the virus, let a virusscanner do the job.